# JSON Query | URL Parameter | JSONPATH

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, jsonpath, json-query

I have an API below and I'm wondering how I can query the "name"? in the URL and also I'm trying to use this API with retrofit.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqZeV.jpg

```
{
"code": 200,
"status": "OK",
"data": {
    "surahs": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "name": "سُورَةُ ٱلْفَاتِحَةِ",
            "englishName": "Al-Faatiha",
            "englishNameTranslation": "The Opening",
            "revelationType": "Meccan",
            "ayahs": [
            .
            .
            . 
            ]
        },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: What do you mean under query? Maybe you want to parse it?

Comment: @Yurii I want to get the name of each one in "surahs"

Comment: In which way? Provide some code please, not clear enough what to want to achieve.

Comment: @Yurii
 I tried this but it doesn't work:
http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/quran/quran-uthmani$.data.surahs[*].name

Comment: You can't achieve it like from URL , its it already rendered JSON, so you should Parse it as JSON

Comment: @Yurii, Ok, How can I retrieve it in retrofit, which annotation do I need? "@Path" or "@Query"

Comment: No annotations, because it already returned json data, you should parse it, something like here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-parsing-in-android-using-retrofit-library/